# interrupt() on Thread does not necessarily throw InterruptedExeption when join() is called

Tags: java, exception, interrupted-exception

I have a main class which starts another `thread` like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var worker = new Worker(Thread.currentThread());
        worker.start();
        try {
            worker.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The other thread interrupts the main thread in its `run()`-method:

```
public class Worker extends Thread {

    private final Thread master;
    public Worker(Thread master) {
        this.master = master;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        master.interrupt();
    }
}
```

I'd expect that the main thread throws always an `InterruptedException` since the documentation for `join()` states:
"Throws:
InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown."

But why does it only throw sometimes an InterruptedException?

I've inspected the join method and detected that the `join()` method checks first if a thread is alive before `wait()` is called. This could explain why an InterruptedExeption in not thrown?

Comment: My guess: The main thread wakes up and returns from the call to `join()` due to the worker thread terminating before the interruption is "processed". If you add a call to `Thread.sleep(1)` after the call to `join()` you'll always see an interrupted exception being thrown (from the `sleep` call most of the time; occasionally from the `join` call). Note if the worker thread is a virtual thread, the interrupted exception appears to always be thrown by the `join` call. At least, this is the behavior I see with Java 21.0.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've seen the same behavior. You can also `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` which shows that the flag is set. With virtual threads I couldn't provoke the behavior described in my question.